# Synonyms, storing weights in document for relevance scoring in Elastic Search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, synonym

The story: Given the example documents below and by extending them, is it possible to get the following ranking:

- A search on "Cereals" results in the following ranking

  1. Cornflakes
  2. Rice Krispies
- A search on "Rice" results in the following ranking

  1. Basmati
  2. Rice Krispies

The documents against the search is performed:

```
[{
  name: "Cornflakes"
},
{
  name: "Basmati"
},
{
  name: "Rice Krispies"
}]
```

Of course, some of them does not even held the search term, so an option is to add an array of synonyms with a text value and weight with would help in computing the ranking:

```
[{
  name: "Cornflakes",
  synonyms: [
    {t: 'Cereals', weight: 100},
    {t: 'Sugar', weight: 100}]
},
{
  name: "Basmati",
  synonyms: [
    {t: 'Cereals', weight: 1},
    {t: 'Rice', weight: 1000}]
},
{
  name: "Rice Krispies",
  synonyms: [
    {t: 'Cereals', weight: 10},
    {t: 'Rice', weight: 1}]
}]
```

Is it the right approach?

What is the Elastic Search query for taking into account weighted synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "tags" would be a more appropriate name for the field than "synonyms".
You could use a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html) to store tags and use [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to combine the value of the *tags.weight* field (of the best matching tag if any) with the match score on the *name* field.

One such implementation could look as follows:

```
put test

put test/tag_doc/_mapping
{
    "properties" : {
        "tags" : { 
            "type" : "nested" ,
            "properties": {
                "t" : {"type" : "string"},
                "weight" : {"type" : "double"}
             }

        }   
    }
}

put test/tag_doc/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "tag_doc", "_id":1} }
{"name": "Cornflakes","tags": [{"t": "Cereals", "weight":100},{"t": "Sugar", "weight": 100}]}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "tag_doc","_id":2} }
{ "name": "Basmati","tags": [{"t": "Cereals", "weight": 1},{"t": "Rice", "weight": 1000}]}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "tag_doc","_id":3} }
{ "name": "Rice Krispies", "tags": [{"t": "Cereals", "weight": 10},{"t": "Rice", "weight": 1}]}


post test/_search
{
   "query": {
      "dis_max": {
         "queries": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "name": {
                     "query": "cereals",
                     "boost": 100
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "tags",
                  "query": {
                     "function_score": {
                        "functions": [
                           {
                              "field_value_factor": {
                                 "field": "tags.weight"
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "query": {
                           "match": {
                              "tags.t": "cereals"
                           }
                        },
                        "boost_mode": "replace",
                        "score_mode": "max"
                     }
                  },
                  "score_mode": "max"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Result** :

```
"hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 100,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "tag_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 100,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Cornflakes",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "t": "Cereals",
                     "weight": 100
                  },
                  {
                     "t": "Sugar",
                     "weight": 100
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "tag_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 10,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Rice Krispies",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "t": "Cereals",
                     "weight": 10
                  },
                  {
                     "t": "Rice",
                     "weight": 1
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "tag_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Basmati",
               "tags": [
                  {
                     "t": "Cereals",
                     "weight": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "t": "Rice",
                     "weight": 1000
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```